# Jquery toggle not working when toggling back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery toggle, to show one image and then when the user clicks on an element, change to another image and if they click again show the original image. Like an open close kind of thing. It works when I first click, but nothing after that. Here is my jquery

```
 $(".filterInventory").on("click", function () {

    $(".inventory-search").toggle();
    $(".filer-arrow.down").hide();
    $(".filer-arrow.up").show();

    return false;

});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div class="container container-padding-top inventory-search-button">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="#" class="filterInventory">Filter <img src="~/Images/icons/down-arrow-white.png" class="filer-arrow down" alt="Filter Arrow" /><img src="~/Images/icons/up-arrow-white.png" class="filer-arrow up" alt="Filter Arrow" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#communities a.filterInventory img.up {
    display: none;
}

#communities .filterInventory .filer-arrow {
    height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `toggleClass()` two classes? Additionally, `toggleClass()` takes the *class name*, not a selector, therefore you should have no preceding `.`. If you're trying to toggle both classes, break it out into two lines: `... toggleClass("button-down"); ... toggleClass("button-up");`

Comment: `.button-down .button-up` should be without the period (dot)

Comment: Where's the HTML that goes with `$("#communities .inventory-search button.dropdown-toggle")`?

Comment: Use class names without dot .toggleClass ("class_name") and only one name at once. If you want to do it in one expression, use .toggleClass.apply(null ,['name1', 'name2'])

Comment: My bad I posted the wrong code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide one of the image initally

```
$('img.down').hide();
```

Then simply toggle between them

```
$(".filterInventory").click(function () {
    $(".filterInventory img").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide one image initially and then on click toggle images.

How about this approach ?

HTML:

```
<div id="infoToggler"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text"/>
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/Dummy-Text" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#infoToggler").click(function() {
  $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/522/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#communities .inventory-search button.dropdown-toggle").on("click", function () {

        $("#communities .inventory-search button.dropdown-toggle").toggleClass('button-down', !state).toggleClass('button-up',state);

    });
```

just jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if one of them is visible and then do actions on them through that.

```
$(".filterInventory").on("click", function () {
    if($(".filer-arrow.down").is(":visible")) {
      $(".filer-arrow.down").hide();
      $(".filer-arrow.up").show();
    } else {
      $(".filer-arrow.up").hide();
      $(".filer-arrow.down").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since one of your images is already hidden (assuming from your css you have a #communities element around the html) you can simply toggle them. Instead of targeting the img elements like another answer, this one selects all elements by class:

```
$(".filterInventory").on("click", function () {

    $(".filer-arrow.down, .filer-arrow.up, .inventory-search").toggle();
    return false;
});
```